# 2 possible outcomes: 1 strongly desired

Tags: idiom-requests, phrase-requests, metaphors

I'm looking for a powerful way to describe the fact that -after performing a certain activity- there are only two possible outcomes:

*1) It's a great success (only in 20% of cases)*

*2) It's of no or little use and can even do you some harm (in 80% of cases)*

I would like to use this description to convince people that they should do everything they can to ensure their efforts result in outcome number 1.

Context:

I would like to use this in the context of writing online content: 20% of content generates 90% of engagement. So if you are going to create an online publication, you'd better give it some serious attention so it ends up at the right side/staple that actually generates engagement.

I've considered:

> Your work will either end up at the 20% 'staple' that does it all or at the 80% 'staple' that does you no good at all.

Yet, it feels like that description lacks power and elegance.

I'm open to phrases, expressions, idioms and metaphors. Ideally, it creates a feeling of urgency and it is easy to understand/picture for almost any reader.

---

I've found [this other topic](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/402687/phrase-to-describe-high-contrast-in-the-possible-outcomes), but I don't think it's a duplicate. Although the topic starter is also asking for an idiom with high contrast in possible outcomes, my outcome number 2 is not negative per definition: it can be slightly positive. 
Therefore, the suggestions *'going all in'* (where you lose it all), *'double-edged sword'* and *'high risk/high reward'* don't cover it.

Comment: We need more context, but I've attempted to give you an answer below.

Comment: Thank you @DavidM. I've added the context in which I would like to use it. Does this help for coming up with suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your edit. This paragraph will better fit the context you've provided.

> Remember, the top 20% of your content drives 90% of the interest in your site. The other 80%, at best generates little interest and, at worst drives interest away. So, always strive to be writing that 20%, and in the end all of your content will be better for it.